# Could my website being UTF-8, and database being Latin1, cause Insert errors?

Tags: sql, text, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am just trying to see if this is the reason for a recent bug:

Values in a certain table are sometimes NOT inserted properly, this seems to have arisen after a change I made to the text-encoding on this website, from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 because of text display errors on the website itself. At the time, I did not know this could cause DB errors, but the DB is encoded in Latin1 which I believe is the same as ISO-8859-1.

Could the page with forms, being UTF-8, trying to inserts into a Latin1 db, cause a HARD insertion error for certain queries -- that is, the query fails entirely, as opposed to entering in strange character strings due to encoding mismatch?

EDIT -- I am asking because I cannot myself replicate the insertion bug, I can only observe that it has happened twice to other users. These users do not seem to use special characters in their registration, which adds to the confusion...

Thank you sincerely for your help and time,

-H

Comment: The error should be in the code that decodes the utf-8 and then tries to reencode as iso8859-1, when you have a unicode codepoint that's not available in iso8859-1. If you don't actually have such a reencoding step, your data is all garbage anyway.

Comment: @Wooble -- thank you for your reply, I am unfamiliar with the decoding/reencoding code you referred to. In case my Googling of this isn't completely successful, would you mind being more specific? I am working on a long-existing codebase, so as I am not the original author, I do not currently have complete knowledge of all the involved code that may or may not exist, or where it would be stored if it does. Actually, since I made the change, there is probably not a reencoding step, do I write this into the php right before the Insert, I assume?